# HTML-Page does not play video

Tags: html, video

I am creating a HTML-Page for my local PC for fun and want to implement a video player.
I searched for how to do it and found something which I applied to my page:

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="Videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source>
</video>
```

I even tried to embed the source attribute:

```
<video width="400" src="Videos/test.mp4" controls></video>
```

Both end up creating a video frame with play button but nothing is played. Even when I click on the play button nothing reacts to my click.

[image]

Does anyone unterstand why?

Comment: Have you tried `<iframe>`?

Comment: @debugger can you give me an example how?

Comment: What errors are in your console?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are using `<source>` tag twice. And you can't use an empty `<source>`. It should be like :

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="Videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

reference  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it may be work if your src path not correct

```
Videos/test.mp4 => /Videos/test.mp4

  <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="/Videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source>
  </video>
```

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the DevTools (F12) network tab for any errors while fetching the video file. Probably your answer will be there.

Most likely, this has something to do with the file path you've entered in the `[src]` attribute.

From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_src.asp:

> Possible values:
>
> - An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
>   src="http://www.example.com/movie.ogg")
> - A relative URL - points to a
>   file within a web site (like src="movie.ogg")

Comment: I looked into the Devtools under network for the GET of the mp4. It returned status 200 OK and the path in the request URL is correct

Comment: Take a look at the DevTools Console tab, and check for errors there. Which browser are you using?

Comment: No error messages. I use chrome. I tested my index.html on Edge, but it did not work their either

Comment: Is the video actually working locally? If yes, than I think you should post some print screens so we can try to fix it.